# put awk command into a separate file

Tags: bash, awk, terminal

I did make a code and now would like to make a separate file because the code is a bit long to type but I'm having troubles.

This is my code:

```
awk 'NF && $1!~/^@/ && $1!~/^#/' rmsd.xvg | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum[i] += $i; sumsq[i] += ($i)^2}} 
      END {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
      print "\n", sum[i]/NR, sqrt((sumsq[i]-sum[i]^2/NR)/NR)}}' | sort -u
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You should be able to just copy and paste that awk command into a script file as-is. Either with or without the `awk '` and `' rmsd.xvg` / `' | sort -u` bits at the start and end (depending on what you are trying to do). What have you tried? What happened? What are you trying to do **exactly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named `script.awk`, and put:

```
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    sum[i] += $i; sumsq[i] += ($i)^2}
} 
END {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
    print "\n", sum[i]/NR, sqrt((sumsq[i]-sum[i]^2/NR)/NR)
    }
}
```

into it. Then use:

```
awk 'NF && $1!~/^@/ && $1!~/^#/' rmsd.xvg | awk -f script.awk | sort -u
```

But there's no need for two separate `awk` commands. Change the script to:

```
/^[@#]/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    sum[i] += $i; sumsq[i] += ($i)^2}
} 
END {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
    print "\n", sum[i]/NR, sqrt((sumsq[i]-sum[i]^2/NR)/NR)
    }
}
```

Then:

```
awk -f script.awk rmsd.xvg | sort -u
```

Comment: `NF && $1 !~ /^[@#]/` can just be `$1 ~ /^[^@#]/`.

Comment: Even better, it can just be `/^[@#]/`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script as

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'NF && $1!~/^@/ && $1!~/^#/' rmsd.xvg | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum[i] += $i; sumsq[i] += ($i)^2}} 
      END {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
      print "\n", sum[i]/NR, sqrt((sumsq[i]-sum[i]^2/NR)/NR)}}' | sort -u
```

Excecute the script as

```
$ bash fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have *two* `awk` commands. However, the first is just a filter and can trivially be combined with the second. The only issue is that instead of using `NR` in the `END` action, you'll need to keep count of how many records were acted upon by the first action. The two scripts combined, along with the adjustment for `NR`, would look like

```
NF && $1 !~ /^@/ && $1 !~ /^#/ {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        sum[i] += $i
        sumsq[i] += ($i)^2
    }
    record_count++
} 
END {
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        print "\n", sum[i]/record_count, sqrt((sumsq[i]-sum[i]^2/record_count)/record_count)
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that every line has the same number of fields; otherwise, the value of `NF` in the `END` action is just the value of `NF` on the last line, which may or may not have any  meaning.

Once the above is saved in something like `script.awk`, run it with

```
awk -f script.awk rmsd.xvg | sort -u
```